# Convert flex mobile project to flex web project

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, air

I have a flex mobile project and I want to convert it into web-based project. What is the best way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a library project and insert all *non mobile specific* classes and views in there, which can then be used in your mobile project.  Create a new web based project and include said library, then implement your web based layout while reusing as much of the libraries as possible.

If you've followed good practice, you should be able to reuse 90-95% of all the code that was done in your mobile project into your web one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can helpful or relevant http://www.riagora.com/2011/08/flex-mobile-in-the-browser/